# Keep wi-fi connection while asleep?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi, sleep-wake

Right now my MacBook Pro is set to go to sleep after 1 hour and then when I wake it back up, I have to wait for it to find/connect to Wi-Fi again.

How can I maintain the Wi-Fi connection so when I wake the computer, it's already connected?

I'm running OS X 10.9.1 on a Retina MacBook Pro.

Here are my Energy Saver preferences:

[image: Energy Saver Preferences]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If your Mac enters its full sleep state, then your network connections will be disconnected. Your Mac can not be connected to a WiFi network and be asleep at the same time.

You can avoid full sleep by setting your **Computer Sleep** to **Never**. Your MacBook will then sleep all the sub-systems possible when idle, but will remain awake enough to maintain a WiFi network connection.

PowerNap is not the same as full sleep. This is a special state controlled by Apple and, for now, available only to Apple's chosen processes.

Comment: I don't find *Computer Sleep* in El Capitan.

Comment: @Volatil3 see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188682/sleep-timeout-missing-from-the-energy-saver-preferences for more about the changed Energy Saver interface.

Answer (score 5):

See where System Preferences -> Energy Saver says:

Wake for Network Access?  If your mac is asleep it can still be accessed via Wi-Fi, and woken up.

Power Nap wakes up and connects to services and then disconnects, going into  Bonjour Sleep Proxy mode for being woken up again via Wi-Fi.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5963

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774

One thing to note tho, when Power Nap "wakes up" for the brief moment, the screen does not wake up...

Comment: This doesn't sound like a solid answer, if you "believe" it.

Comment: I got rid of the, I believe, pause, because I don't know everything that goes on, but really a -1? wow, so yeah kinda from what I read I could seriously say "I believe" but I don't understand how can with 100% certainty give a guarantee of anything, anything dude... oh well "The sun will come out tomorrow, tomorrow, bet your bottom dollar that tomorrow will be there, what if you die? Bye

Comment: that -1 was not mine.

Comment: My bad, I just need to learn to not use slang, or sargon I guess, but I don't know... seems like quick speech, quick chat, or shortcuts are everywhere, who draws these lines in the sand?

Comment: I would say, SE is not a slang-location if I may call it that way. This is kinda a knowledge base and help for others, thus readability is important.

Comment: @Rob - that would then make it "a kind of", not "kinda" location?  ;)

Comment: @tink Let me slap you in the face with a trout. That post is over 4 years old!

Comment: I prefer salmon ... ;) @Rob ... do mistakes improve with age? ;D