# Sleep timeout missing from the energy saver preferences

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, power-management

I have two Macbook Pros running on Yosemite. The first one is a 17 incher from 4 years ago. I'm able to set the time that it sleeps. The second one is a 15 incher retina made this year. In its energy saver section, I don't see a way to set the sleep time. It only shows the display time. How do I make both slider controls show up on this new Macbook Pro?

[image]

Comment: I can't add a comment because I don't have sufficient reputation, so instead I'm forced to comment by adding an answer. When I discovered the "computer sleep" slider was missing, and then read the above description of why Apple deliberately chose to do this, I exasperatedly exclaimed "But now I have no control over how much time elapses before I am forced to enter a password to resume using the computer!". Well, it turns out Apple exposes that functionality in another section of the Settings app: Security & Privacy -> General -> Require password x minutes after sleep. [![enter image descriptio

Comment: I just checked Apple's page, supposedly updated for Sierra, and it still talks about having a separate slider for the computer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Deliberately Removed

Apple have removed the **Computer** slider from the Energy Saver settings. This is deliberate.

The decision is related to Apple's introduction of improved hardware, Power Nap support, and the engineers' belief that OS X is best placed to manage the computer's power state.

If you would like to see this slider return, provide [feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback).

#### Downloads and Other Long Running Tasks

OS X will stay awake during most long running tasks.

The behaviour will depend on the software downloading the file. Safari and Transmission, for example, both ask OS X to stay awake while a download is ongoing.

Applications need to lodge power assertions with OS X that explicitly stop the computer sleeping. You can see these assertions using the following `pmset` command:

```
pmset -g assertions
```

For older software, you can add this behaviour using the built-in command line tool [caffeinate](http://dssw.co.uk/reference/caffeinate.html).

#### Third Party Alternatives

Third party tools exist to supplement the Energy Saver settings. I created Power Manager and it can [put your Mac to sleep after inactivity](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-04-14-how-to-make-your-mac-sleep-after-inactivity/).

Other tools exist and you could probably create a script to also recreate this behaviour.

Comment: Apparently it is a Haswell "feature" http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=17457370&postcount=11

Comment: @n1000 I didn't understand all that tech jargon in that article. Does that mean when my display sleeps, my computer also sleeps? What if I was downloading a huge file that would take 5 hours to complete? How would I make the display sleep after 15 minutes of activity, but still have the computer on so that the download is not cut off?

Comment: So, does the 'Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off' actually do anything? Or is it equivalent to setting 'Computer Sleep' to 'never' on the old interface?

Comment: @Peter please could you [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). This is the best way to attract answers. Comments are not widely seen.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Safari will download the file but it will not go to sleep.

You can also check the box that says "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off." I have that box unchecked;  power nap really, in this case, does help.  I've actually ended up answering one of my own questions by reading this thread.